# Mongoose.js: how to implement create or update?

Tags: mongoose

I have a request which body contains data and _id

What is the better way to implement code that will update if record with _id exists and will create one is there is no one? My code:

```
var obj = req.body;
Model.findById(obj._id, function(err, data){
    if (!data){
        var model = new Model(obj)
        model.save(function(err, data){
            res.send({method: 'create', error: err, data: data})
        })
    } else {
        Model.findByIdAndUpdate(obj._id, obj, function(){
            res.send({method: 'update', error: err, data: data})
        })
    }
```

I'm just thinking maybe there is beter way of doing this.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can do that with a single [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter):

```js
var obj = req.body;
var id = obj._id;
delete obj._id;
if (id) {
    Model.update({_id: id}, obj, {upsert: true}, function (err) {...});
}
```

The caveat is that your model's defaults and middleware (if any) will not be applied.

**Mongoose 4.x Update**

You can now use the [`setDefaultOnInsert`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#the-setdefaultsoninsert-option) option to also apply defaults if the upsert creates a new document.

```js
Model.update({_id: id}, obj, {upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true}, cb);
```

Comment: The problem is that "obj" contains _id, and in case of update I need to remove it prior update or I get "Mod on _id not allowed" error

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Good point.  Updated the code to remove that before the `update`.

Comment: there is the rub. I want newly created (if it doesn't exists) Item to have _id equal to obj._id, If to remove _id from obj before create operation, mongo will create new _id.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR When I tried this, the newly created item did get an `_id` equal to the value of `obj._id` that was saved off in the `id` value used in the query selector.  The `update` combines both objects when needing to create a new one.

Comment: [Here's a link to the Mongoose Model `update` method, which lists the `upset` option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)

Comment: @JohnnyHK Out of curiosity, why doesn't it apply the Models Defaults?? Strange

Comment: This one ignores my created_at and updated_at pre() method

Comment: @MarkPieszak In Mongoose 4.x, you can now apply defaults during an upsert. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes! I've been waiting for this implementation. I haven't updated to Mongoose 4.x yet but now I definitely am. Thanks @JohnnyHK

Comment: What if I want to updateOrCreate hundereds of docs at once? Is there a batch way?

Comment: Using `.update()` will skip `pre` hook validations if you have any.

Comment: what if the object I want to update has a list and I need to update that list with a new element?

Answer (score 2):

```
 var obj = req.body;
 var id = obj._id;
 delete obj._id;
 model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, obj, {
                     new: true,
                     upsert: true, // Make this update into an upsert
 });
```

Comment: Seems to be better answer as "update" method is deprecated in monoogse

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `update` function was [deprecated with the new versions](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/6.x/docs/deprecations.html#update), the `updateOne` or `findOneAndUpdate` can be used like this:

```js
const { _id, ...updateModel } = req.body;

return await Model.updateOne({ _id }, updateModel, { new: true, upsert: true })
    .then(data => res.send({ method: 'create', error: null, data }))
    .catch(error => res.send({ method: 'update', error, data: null }));
```