# NodeJS express: Logic in update when town already exist

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using NodeJS with express framework and mongoose and I made town input with logic where is no input, right input and already exist input. Maybe there is better solution but this working fine:

```
router.post('/create', (req, res)=>{
    let errors = [];

    if (!req.body.name) {
      errors.push({message: 'Add town name!'});
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      res.render('admin/towns/index', {
        errors: errors,
        name: req.body.name
      });
    } else {
      Town.findOne({name: req.body.name}).then(town=>{
        if (!town) {
          const newTown = Town({
            name: req.body.name
          });
          newTown.save().then(savedTown=>{
            req.flash('success_message', `Town ${savedTown.name} is activated`);
            res.redirect('/admin/towns');
          });
        } else {
          req.flash('error_message', 'Town name already exist!');
          res.redirect('/admin/towns');
        }
      });
    }
});
```

but, when I want to update, where is no input working fine, where name is new also working fine but if name exist it's shows me error:

> (node:12140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000
>   duplicate key error collection: crm_electors.towns index: name_1 dup
>   key: { : "Belgrade" }

```
router.put('/edit/:id', (req, res)=>{
    let errors = [];

    if (!req.body.name) {
      errors.push({message: 'Add town name!'});
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      res.render('admin/towns/index', {
        errors: errors,
        name: req.body.name
      });
    } else {
      Town.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(town=>{
        if (req.body.name !== town) { // I guess this logic is wrong
          town.name = req.body.name;
          town.save().then(savedTown=>{
            req.flash('success_message', 'Town name successfully renamed');
            res.redirect('/admin/towns');
          });
        } else {
          req.flash('error_message', 'Town name already exist!');
          res.redirect('/admin/towns');
        }
      });
    }
});
```

I presume this logic is wrong (req.body.name !== town), so I tried req.body.name !== town.name and some more variations but no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose.js: how to implement create or update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337685/mongoose-js-how-to-implement-create-or-update). I think that thread will show you the better way.

Comment: I don't know, seems to me that is not that similar to this problem or maybe I just can't see how to implement on my code...? That logic that troubles me is missing in your link.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose works on error first callbacks where the callback has `error` as it's first parameter and `result` in the second parameter. The code you have is misleading `error` with `result` as the first parameter in your `findOne` callback is error which you are referencing with variable `town`. Thus, you need to change your code to something like:

```
Town.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, (err, town)=> {
      if (town) {
        //check is this new name already exist or not
        Town.find({name: req.body.name}, (err, townWithName) => {
            if(townWithName){ //if there is already a town with this name
              req.flash('error_message', 'Town name already exist!');
              res.redirect('/admin/towns');
            } else {
              town.name = req.body.name;
              town.save((err, savedTown) => {
                req.flash('success_message', 'Town name successfully renamed');
                res.redirect('/admin/towns');
              });
            }
        });
      } else {
        req.flash('error_message', 'Town with this id do not exist!!');
        res.redirect('/admin/towns');
      }
  });
```

Since, `town` in the second parameter of the callback it holds the mongoose model record. So, you can access `name` property from it. Furthermore, you can also handle runtime error by using that `err` parameter in callback by using this block of code inside callback:

```
if (err) {
   res.send(//some message and code);
}
```

Comment: I add err as first parameter but now this appear: (node:7708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: @NenadM ok then I have edited my answer. use callback function approach by removing `then`

Comment: Now is the same as first problem, update is good until name is duplicate. Then this: (node:4932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: crm_electors.towns index: name_1 dup key: { : "Belgrade" }

Comment: The logic was incorrect @NenadM check now. It should work

Comment: Can you give me a full code because now argument is missing: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list... And I'm not quite sure where to put this: if (err) {
   res.send(//some message and code);
}

Comment: I missed that in answer. Now it is corrected please check the edited code again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167017/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-nenad-m).